# I want to click on a button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I´m trying to web scraping and i need to simulate a click on a buttoN, I´ve tried this:

```
url = "https://apps5.mineco.gob.pe/transparencia/mensual/default.aspx?y=2021&ap=ActProy"
driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
nivelGob = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH1_BtnTipoGobierno"]')
nivelGob.click()
```

and returns me this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ctl00_CPH1_BtnTipoGobierno"]"}
(Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)

I've been trying find the element by css selector, class name but nothing.

This is the button:

[image: Nivel de gobierno]

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is actually within another frame so you need to switch to that frame. Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

url = "https://apps5.mineco.gob.pe/transparencia/mensual/default.aspx?y=2021&ap=ActProy"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
frame = driver.find_element_by_id("frame0")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
w = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_CPH1_BtnTipoGobierno"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the DOM isn't fully loaded yet. Try adding implicit wait to your driver

`driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds`

Comment: I've just tried it, but returns me the same error.